# ionic check network status in background(kill app)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

ionic info
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.0
npm  : 5.6.0 
OS   : macOS High Sierra
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

i used this code

```
this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('connetion');
      if (this.network.type == "wifi") {
        console.log('wifi');
      }
    });
```

this code successful in foreground and background

but if kill this app not work

how to run code in after kill app

Answer (score -1):

> how to run code in after kill app

If your app is killed, you cannot run anything ! It's.... logic